# merge xml elements in one element using xslt-3

Tags: xslt-3.0

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<mr:collection
    xmlns:mr="http://www.lc.gov/mr2/slim"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.lc.gov/mr2/slim http://www.lc.gov/standards/mrxml/schema/mr21slim.xsd">
    <mr:rc>
    <mr:dtf tg="2000" i1="1" i2=" ">
        <mr:sbf cd="a">Christoph Kolumbus</mr:sbf>
        <mr:sbf cd="d">John Diter</mr:sbf>
        <mr:sbf cd="b">Julie Nat</mr:sbf>
        <mr:sbf cd="f">Darius Milhaud</mr:sbf>
        <mr:sbf cd="g">Erich kleiber</mr:sbf>
        <mr:sbf cd="g">Franz Ludwig Horth</mr:sbf>
    </mr:dtf>
    <mr:dtf tg="3000" i1="1" i2=" ">
        <mr:sbf cd="a">Christoph Kolumbus</mr:sbf>
        <mr:sbf cd="d">Serg</mr:sbf>
        <mr:sbf cd="b">Mak</mr:sbf>
        <mr:sbf cd="f">DarMil</mr:sbf>
        <mr:sbf cd="g">Erikl</mr:sbf>
        <mr:sbf cd="g">LudHorth</mr:sbf>
    </mr:dtf>
</mr:rc>
<mr:rc>
<mr:dtf tg="2000" i1="1" i2="0">
    <mr:sbf cd="a">Chris Prante</mr:sbf>
    <mr:sbf cd="e">&quot;Chris Dietz&quot;</mr:sbf>
</mr:dtf>
</mr:rc>
</mr:collection>
```

i need to create a new xml file, by merging the elements that have the value <mr:dtf tg="2000" (irrelevant of what follows in i1 and i2 values),and of course there are other elements in the input xmlfiles with different values,ie <mr:dtf tg="3000" in the following way: the new value of the new single element that will be created will consist of the value of cd a, then a space character and the value of cd b, then a space character, the : character,again a space character, then the value of cd e, then a space character, the / character,again a space character, then the value of cd f, then a space character, the ; character,again a space character, then the value of cd g,only if the above cd elements exist.

Desired output:

```
<O-PM xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.op.org/O/2.0/ http://www.op.org/O/2.0/O-PM.xsd">
<ListRcs>
    <rc>
        <mtdt>
            <e:rc>
                <d:title xml:lang="el">Christoph Kolumbus Julie Nat / Darius Milhaud ; Erich kleiber ; Franz Ludwig Horth</d:title>
            </e:rc>
        </mtdt>
    </rc>
    <rc>
        <mtdt>
            <e:rc>
                <d:title xml:lang="el">Chris Prante : &quot;Chris Dietz&quot;</d:title>
            </e:rc>
        </mtdt>
    </rc>
</ListRcs>
```

I have tried only with xsl:value-of select, getting not the result i need... is there a more clever - efficient way to do this? Thank you

Comment: You have two `mr:dtf` elements in the input which seem to be mapped to two result elements so I don't see any attempt to merge these elements based on the `tg="2000"` value, as your text suggests. As for concatenating all those values from the various `mr:sbf` as a single value of the `d:title` result element, yes, use `xsl:value-of` or text value templates. But in the end it is not clear which elements can appear, which ones only occur together, whether the various separators between some of them need to appear only if the elements exists.

Comment: thank you or your kind reply, for each rc, , and for mr:dtf with the value of 2000, i need to merge the values of  mr:sbf cd="a", mr:sbf cd="b", mr:sbf cd="e",mr:sbf cd="f", mr:sbf cd="g",into one element, <d:title xml:lang="el">separated by the diacritics i describe in the question above. Also, the various separators between some of them need to appear only if the elements exists, as you may see in the second rc.Please note also that there are two mr:sbf cd="g". Hope the desired output helps make clear what i try to create

Comment: No, the desired output lacks namespace declarations, doesn't make it clear what is supposed to have with the `mr:dtf tg="3000"` your text says you also have. Also, it is kind of hard to read the sample for persons like me that don't speak or know the language (Greek?) to identify which data ends up in which position. Show us what you have as XSLT so far and how it fails.

Comment: changed all characters to latin ones in the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is kind of hard to cater for all options of missing or existing items, perhaps the following helps as it outputs certain separators only if the item itself exists; nevertheless I haven't got the exact output, hopefully you can adjust the code to your needs:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.lc.gov/mr2/slim"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="collection">
    <O-PM>
        <ListRcs>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ListRcs>
    </O-PM>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="rc">
      <rc>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </rc>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="dtf[@tg = 2000]">
      <mdtd>
          <rc>
              <title xml:lang="el">{sbf[@cd = 'a']} {sbf[@cd = 'b']}{sbf[@cd = 'e']!(':', .)} {sbf[@cd = 'f']!('/', .)}{(sbf[@cd = 'g'] => string-join(' ; '))!('', .)}</title>
          </rc>
      </mdtd>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="dtf[@tg != 2000]"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Namespaces for the output were not declared so I have put everything in no namespace.

Example at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNEj9dR.

Comment: my xslt was quite different. ie one issue i had and i still have is the following:i have xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" so as to declare dc. But in the end result i get: <dc:title xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xml:lang="el">. How the declaration should be, so as to get only <dc:title xml:lang="el">?

Comment: i tried to upload here my xslt and yours but i am not getting any transformation as output: http://xsltransform.net/

Comment: Please ask about new issues in separate questions with all the necessary details

Comment: @wowefiq, I have added a link to an online fiddle using your input and my code sample. As I said in the answer, I ignored any namespaces in the output sample you showed as it lacks any namespace declarations.

Comment: how one could remove the empty spaces found in he end,after "Chris Dietz"?<dc:title xml:lang="el">Chris Prante : "Chris Dietz"  </dc:title>

Comment: @wowefiq, I don't have a clear pictures where spaces are needed and it might be easier to use several steps of processing, perhaps a second `normalize-space` steps helps e.g. `<xsl:variable name="title" as="xs:string">{sbf[@cd = 'a']} {sbf[@cd = 'b']}{sbf[@cd = 'e']!(':', .)} {sbf[@cd = 'f']!('/', .)}{(sbf[@cd = 'g'] => string-join(' ; '))!('', .)}</xsl:variable><title xml:lang="el">{normalize-space($title)}</title>`.